# a4j:support tag not found using JSF 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

just trying to integrate this commandLink

```
<a4j:commandLink reRender="results-view" actionListener="#{myaction}" oncomplete="return false;" value="#{msg1.advanced_search}">
                            <a4j:support event="onclick">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="./page.xhtml" target="#{changeViews['new-view'].value}" />
                            </a4j:support>
                        </a4j:commandLink>
```

On an applicacion which is using JSF2. If I leave it, I get this error

> Tag Library supports
>   namespace: http://richfaces.org/a4j,
>   but no tag was defined for name:
>   support

I was trying to find something on the net, but I couldn't figure out. Some help would be great.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `a4j:support` has been replaced by `a4j:ajax` since RichFaces 4.x.

You seem to be reading RichFaces 3.x documentation or just have upgraded RichFaces 3.x to 4.x. This is a pretty major step where a lot of things are been changed. Read the [migration guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration) (in this particular case, it's described in [a4j components](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-Componentsmigration-a4jComponents)) and also read the new RF4 [component reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.CR1/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/).