# JSF 1.2- >2.0 :viewId parameter for save view state is null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2, myfaces

We are migrating our JSF 1.2 project to JSF 2.0  and using a command button in a JSP page .Clicking command button get a reponse from external system and display response.

While clicking this command button we are getting blank page with below execption

During debug I found that we are getting a success response but its not able to find original page as it lost state view ID

```
[8/13/13 11:01:30:538 CDT] 000000e0 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.NullPointerException: viewId parameter for  save view state is null
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.saveState(AjaxStateHolder.java:155)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveStateInSession(AjaxStateManager.java:523)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.buildViewState(AjaxStateManager.java:503)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveView(AjaxStateManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:169)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
```

Is there any specific config required in web.xml to save view state ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of Ajax4jsf 1.x specific `org.ajax4jsf.*` classes in the stacktrace tells that you're still using Ajax4jsf for JSF 1.x.

This is **not compatible** with JSF 2.x. You must remove all Ajax4jsf 1.x related JAR files and registrations in `web.xml`. You need to use JSF's own `<f:ajax>` facilities instead, or to upgrade to RichFaces 4.x which bundles a newer, JSF 2.0 compatible, version of `<a4j:xxx>` tags. Note that this in turn requires Facelets instead of JSP. So you have to migrate from JSP to Facelets as well.

#### See also:

- [Migrating JSF 1.1 with Ajax4jsf 1.x to JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553033/migrating-jsf-1-1-with-ajax4jsf-1-x-to-jsf-2/)
- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/)
- [a4j:support tag not found using JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402697/a4jsupport-tag-not-found-using-jsf-2/)