# WebSphere 7.0 to 8.5 upgrade - JSF - viewId parameter for save view state is null

Tags: jsf, websphere, jsf-1.2

I am trying to migrate a lot of applications from WebSphere 7.0 to 8.5, and am coming up with an issue with JSF. I am getting:

> viewId parameter for save view state is null

We are on JSF 1.2. I've provided the stack trace below - I am not sure what other information I need to provide. Doing a search only returns issues with upgrading to JSF 2.0 from 1.2, but that's not the case here.

Has anyone got any ideas or has seen this before?

Thanks in advance

```
[14/10/15 14:39:20:757 BST] 0000009f ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId parameter for  save view state is null
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:221)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at uk.co.martinmccoll.funding.filters.LogonFilter.doFilter(LogonFilter.java:56)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:919)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: viewId parameter for  save view state is null
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.saveState(AjaxStateHolder.java:155)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveStateInSession(AjaxStateManager.java:539)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.buildViewState(AjaxStateManager.java:519)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveSerializedView(AjaxStateManager.java:467)
at com.ibm.faces.application.DevelopmentStateManager.saveSerializedView(DevelopmentStateManager.java:33)
at javax.faces.application.StateManager.saveView(StateManager.java:114)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
... 27 more

[14/10/15 14:39:20:758 BST] 0000009f webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.NullPointerException: viewId parameter for  save view state is null
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.saveState(AjaxStateHolder.java:155)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveStateInSession(AjaxStateManager.java:539)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.buildViewState(AjaxStateManager.java:519)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.saveSerializedView(AjaxStateManager.java:467)
at com.ibm.faces.application.DevelopmentStateManager.saveSerializedView(DevelopmentStateManager.java:33)
at javax.faces.application.StateManager.saveView(StateManager.java:114)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at uk.co.martinmccoll.funding.filters.LogonFilter.doFilter(LogonFilter.java:56)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:919)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

Comment: The stack-trace may help identify / solve the problem. You must have already visited [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18214291/1391249) question which shows some incompatibilities among APIs so is possibly your case.

Comment: I've added a stack trace to the post. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are really using JSF 1.2 in newer WebSphere 8.5? The stack-trace matches the linked question implying it attempts to use at least JSF 2.0. (Disclaimer : I am not aware of WebSphere nor RichFaces).

Comment: It's definitely using JSF1.2, which is what is confusing. Richfaces is also being used, so I think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere 8.5 is compatible with JSF 2.0 from [IBM API Specification](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html).  The best approach is to migrate the applications to JSF 2.0 because 1.2 is deprecated.