# a4j:htmlCommandLink in RichFaces 4

Tags: jsf, migration, richfaces

I've been migrating to RichFaces 4.5.2 and while parsing the pages into xhtml format I ran into the following error:

> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/a4j, but no tag was defined for name: htmlCommandLink

My quesion is what is the re-placer of this component in RichFaces 4?

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5402697/1391249). (I am not familiar with RichFaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the RichFaces 4 removed the a4j:htmlCommandLink, as it's not included in the [component reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.CR1/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/).

In my opinion, you can just use the `<a4j:commandLink>`:

> The `<a4j:commandLink>` component is similar to the JavaServer Faces
>   (JSF) `<h:commandLink>` component, except that it includes plugged-in
>   Ajax behavior.